Gravitational halos made of neutrinos...?
I have been recently interested in how halos made of standard model particles could be formed and behave.
After asking some questions in this site, I was told about how neutrinos could form such halos.
One good reference that I was given is arxiv:hep-ph/0408241, in which the authors studied that neutrinos could form "halos" around sufficiently large dark matter (and baryonic matter) gravitational potentials.
Although I find it interesting, I have a bit of a trouble understanding some parts of the paper. For example, apparently in their classical halo calculations, they say they do not consider classical galaxy-neutrino “bound states”, like the sun-earth one. But if they do not consider classical galaxy-neutrino gravitational "bound states" how can they study the gravitational clustering of neutrinos around cold dark matter and baryonic matter structures? I mean, gravitational clustering means that the neutrinos are being attracted by gravity thus forming a (gravitational) bound state with those structures, right?
Also, I have been told that neutrino halos likely have little angular momentum, just like other dark matter halo models. But although is likely that they have low angular momentum, is it at least physically possible that a rare neutrino halo may have a high angular momentum? Or since the neutrinos would be weakly bounded even a small amount of angular momentum could risk them being expelled from the halo? Also, even if they have low angular momentum, if we have a large enough neutrino halo, could the total angular momentum be large (as we would have a lot of mass in form of neutrino particles)?

Possibly-related question with lots of links. But compare with 'Oumuamua, which approached the Sun without being gravitationally bound, and ask yourself whether a gas of such objects might have an overdensity near a gravitational attractor, even without any bound states.

so you mention "classical bound states", which implies there is a quantum bound state. I've hear some talk of superfluid dark matter halos--is that what we're talking about? Or, the kinda cute question: what does the hydrogen Schrödinger equation look like, but with $G$ and $m_{\nu}$. Since the Bohr radius $a_0\propto \lambda_{Compton}/\alpha$, it's pretty big.

We expect the neutrino (or other dark matter) directions in a halo to be fairly randomised. (Also, cold neutrinos don't have much momentum).

@rob so it's possible that a gas of neutrinos may clump around ovdrdensities even if they are nit gravitationally bounded to them?

Look, I haven't done any math about this, nor read the paper. But I would use "clump" to describe particles in bound states, which you say are excluded in the analysis.  I meant to suggest that the unbound neutrinos might be more dense near a massive galaxy than in the emptier intergalactic region. Another related question, with some more recent links.

@PM2Ring even if individual particles are randomized, wouldn't the whole halo have a total angular momentum? (Like planets in the milky way that have random local directions but they have angular momentum as a whole)

@vengaq Sure, it's unlikely for the total angular momentum of the halo to be zero. OTOH, it's not like a cloud of baryonic matter condensing to create a star system, which preserves its initial angular momentum. The neutrinos in the halo arrive from all directions, over a long time span. Astrophysicist Pela discusses dark matter halo formation here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/14433/16685

@PM2Ring so if we had a very large neutrino halo (or dark matter halo) couldn't the halo as a whole have a very big angular momentum (due to its large mass) despite the individual random motions of the particles? Or this would be completely impossible?

@vengaq Please don't delete and repost comments just to refresh someone's notifications. If you want to draw more attention to a question, post a bounty.
